# convert mysql query in to an array format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

can any one know the, convert mysql query in to an php array:

this is mysql query :

```
SELECT SUM(time_spent) AS sumtime, title, url 
FROM library 
WHERE delete_status = 0 
GROUP BY url_id 
ORDER BY sumtime DESC
```

I want to convert this query in to simple php array .

Comment: Your question is confusing. For the given input, what is your desired output.

Comment: should really read about how mysql php works http://phpsense.com/php/php-mysql.html

Comment: i want convert this query in to an normal php array loop format

Comment: *Normal* "array loop format?"  Nothing in PHP is normal!  There are *at least four different formats* for an array coming back from that query.  Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you need to get data out of MySQL.  The best way, hands down, to fetch data from MySQL using PHP is [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), a cross-database access interface.

So, first let's connect.

```
// Let's make sure that any errors cause an Exception.
// <http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php>
    PDO::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// We need some credentials...
    $user = 'username';
    $pass = 'password';
    $host = 'hostname';
    $dbname = 'database';
// PDO wants a "data source name," made up of those credentials.
// <http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php>
    $dsn = "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
```

There, we've connected.  Let's pretend that `$sql` has the SQL you provided in your question.  Let's run the SQL:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

There, it's been executed.  Let's talk about results.  You steadfastly refuse to tell us how you want your data structured, so let's go through four ways that you could get your data.

Let's first assume that the query returns a single row.  If you want a *numerically indexed array*, you would do this:

```
// <http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php>
    $array = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    unset($statement);
```

If you want an *associative array with the column names as the keys*, you would do this:

```
    $array = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    unset($statement);
```

Now, what if the query returns more than one record?  If we want *each row in a numerically indexed array*, with each row as an associative array, we would do this:

```
// <http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php>
    $array = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    unset($statement);
```

What if we want each row as a numerically indexed array instead?  Can you guess?

```
    $array = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    unset($statement);
```

Tada.  You now know how to query MySQL using the modern PDO interface and get your results as no less than four types of array.  There's a tremendous number of other cool things that you can do in PDO with very minimal effort.  Just follow the links to the manual pages, which I have quite intentionally not linked for you.

This over-the-top post has been brought to you by the letters T, F and W, and the number `PHP_MAX_INT + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

i don't get you clearly, but

**mysql_fetch_array** and  **mysql_fetch_assoc**

both returns only array

please refer:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a *simple* array...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { //you can assume rest of the code, right?
    $result[$row['url_id']] = array($row['sumtime']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple array

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(time_spent) AS sumtime, title, url 
FROM library 
WHERE delete_status = 0 
GROUP BY url_id 
ORDER BY sumtime DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $array1 = $row['sumtime'];
    $array2 = $row['title'];
    $array3 = $row['url'];
}
```

Hope this is one you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Dude the fastest way is probably the following

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $data[] = $row; 
} 

print_r($data);
```